# Phantom items are being printed with no commands

Tags: php, ini

On creating a sparse few pages in my web directory, there is an extremely large amount of debug that is outputted with no commands. The debug in question seems to be in relation to a table which I have below the outputted debug. The debug in question is seen here:

http://gyazo.com/28bafa37238fc5c17753cdf64611cc81.png

Which corresponds to the output:

http://gyazo.com/e14f399b18fe6ddafa3882c3c8aff5e9.png

The only explanation that I can think of to cause this phenomenon is that the php.ini file is allowing it somewhere, yet I have no idea what is causing this. Previous to asking this question, there was an additional line in between the < number>Start and < number>html parts with < number>magic. This was solved by adding the lines:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

to my php.ini.

If anyone has any ideas as to what option affects this in the php.ini file, that would be much appreciated as any searches for this particular output have turned up as naught.

An additional point is that the PHP build on this hosting provider is still in 5.3.25.

The code relating to the table is as follows:

```
$out = "<table align='center'><th>Proofer</th>
  <th>Story</th>
  <th>Author</th>
  <th>Delete</th>";
sqlConnect();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `story` ORDER BY `st_name`";
$res = mysql_query( $sql );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $res ) ) {
  $out .= "<tr><td><a href='./profile?u=" . $row['user_id'] . "'>". proofBy( $row['user_id'] ) ."</a></td>";
  $out .= "<td><a href='". $row['st_link'] ."'>". $row['st_name'] ."</a></td>";
  $out .= "<td><a href='". $row['a_link'] ."'>". $row['author'] ."</a></td>";
  $out .= "<td><a href='./storyMaster?d=". $row['st_id'] ."'>Delete</a></td>";
  $out .= "</tr>";
}
mysql_close();
$out .= "</table>";
```

This is the only segment of code which seems like it would have the necessary impact due to the looping nature given here.

Comment: We'll need to see some code if you want us to help.

Comment: @Dave Apologies, code has been added.

Comment: can you give us your sqlConnect() function too.  There's no flags in the php.ini which would cause it to output partial sql pull data like that so there's gotta be something in your code that does it ir could be your connection or it could be your proofBy() function, I can't see anything wrong at first glance (apart from using mysql_ not mysqli_ or pdo) but thats not to say there isn't something I've missed.

Comment: @Dave Admittedly I find myself feeling rather idiotic... my proofBy function goes through an sqlSanitise function which had debug code left in for some god forsaken reason. I now feel like an idiot and my output is back to normal. Apologies for the time spent on this.

Comment: at least you now know :)

Answer (score 0):

The moral of this particular story is to check your own debug code first...
*applauds self for being an idiot*